# Accessing a WCF service from Windows 8

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-8

I'm trying to access a webservice from a Windows 8 device. The credentials I need to provide are those of a domain account of the domain where the ECF service is hosted. My Windows 8 device is not in this domain (as it should run on WinRT devices it might not be in a domain at all).

I can't get the authentication to work. I tried using HttpCredentialTypes Basic, Ntlm and Windows and tried to combine this with the different ways to set the username.

I get this error:

```
The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM,Basic realm="webservice.company.com"'. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
```

I also tried to change SecurityMode (Transport, TransportWithMessageCredential) but that did not help.

When I try to access the service using a local account (that is an account local to the webserver) it works using Basic and Transport.

**Edit:** The Webservice works over SSL so I have to use https.